# Ignoring empty values on AutoMapper with .NET Core 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, automapper

I am using .NET Core 7.0 and AutoMapper.Dependency 12.

I am sending a JSON object as below to the `Company` table via Postman.

Automatically "null" from database when some values are empty replaces with.

I have a structure like below, and I want to ignore null values

The `companyUpdateDTO` object may have some columns blank by the user, so how can I ignore the blank values that come with dto?

I want to do this globally via AutoMapper. But in no way could I ignore the empty values.

***The JSON object I sent: I am not submitting the "description" field, so it is changed to "null" in the database.***

```
{
  "id": 1002,
  "name": "xcv"
}
```

`Company` entity:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

`CompanyUpdateDTO` class:

```
public class CompanyUpdateDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile));
```

AutoMapper profile:

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        AllowNullCollections = true;

        #region Company DTO
        CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Company, CompanyCreateDto>().ReverseMap();
        //CreateMap<Company, CompanyUpdateDto>().ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<Company, CompanyUpdateDto>().ReverseMap().ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't understand the problem within .Net. You have a two classes. Both have a nullable property. What is the problem if you apply the null value? Even after calling the default ctor the instance would have the null value and setting it again to null doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I guess you somewhere in your code serialize the DTO into a JSON object to send it to an API and this serializer has to ignore null values on serialization (as said just a guess).

Comment: yes, I want to exclude "null" incoming values with automapper.

Comment: that is, the json columns that I send with postman may not always be filled by the user. So I want to ignore the empty columns

Comment: This has nothing to do with .Net, AutoMapper or serialization. It's all about design. The DTO doesn't match the job it's supposed to do and/or EF isn't used properly.

Comment: Got it, so how can I ignore the null values from the global?

Comment: So the columns in the incoming dto object may not always be full.

Comment: Basically, don't do anything with Description in the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two-fold. At first you receive a JSON and you deserialize it into a DTO (by the way, what serialize do you use??). Afterwards you can't distinguish if the value of a property was explictly set or if it still has its default value.

In a second step you convert this DTO into another object by using AutoMapper and send this to your database. In case of an update, how to you read the existing entity from your database and how do you make the update call?

Let's start by trying to distinguish between explicitly set values and omitted values. To solve this problem, you have to define *magic values* for each type that can be omitted. Really think about these values and try to find values, that will really never be used, because you can't distinguished between the omitted value and an explicitly set value of exact that value! For example:

```
public static class Omitted
{
    public static readonly int Integer = int.MinValue;
    public static readonly string String = "{omitted}";
    public static readonly DateTime DateTime = DateTime.MaxValue;
}
```

By having this bunch of defaults you have to slightly adjust your DTO classes and apply these omitted values by default:

```
public class CompanyUpdateDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = Omitted.Integer;
    public string? Name { get; set; } = Omitted.String;
    public string? Description { get; set; } = Omitted.String;
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; } = Omitted.DateTime;
}
```

If you have prepared your DTO accordingly and you deserialize your JSON into a new instance you can distinguish between the values has been explicitly set to null or omitted by comparison.

In a next step we need to convert from the DTO to the entity object of the database. Due to the fact, that you make an update I guess you read the entity from database and use AutoMapper to apply a source object onto an existing target object. A rough sketch would be:

```
// Create DTO from json
var dto = CreateObjectFrom(json);

// Read existing instance from database
var existing = await database.Companies.FirstAsync(c => c.Id == dto.Id);

// Map DTO on existing entity and avoid omitted values
mapper.Map<CompanyUpdateDto, Company>(dto, existing);

// Save changes to database
await database.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Unfortunately to conditionally omit the update if a property has its magic value we have to explicitly define them all in the mapping profile:

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CompanyUpdateDto, Company>()
            .ForMember(c => c.Name, dto => dto.Condition((_, _, value) => NotOmitted.String(value)))
            .ForMember(c => c.Description, dto => dto.Condition((_, _, value) => NotOmitted.String(value)));
    }
}
```

We just need the next helper class as already mentioned in code:

```
public static class NotOmitted
{
    public static bool Integer(int value) => value == Omitted.Integer;
    public static bool String(string value) => value == Omitted.String;
    public static bool DateTime(DateTime value) => value == Omitted.DateTime;
}
```

With this approach you can distinguish, if a value in JSON was omitted or explicitly set to `null` and by using the `.Condition()` call within AutoMapper you can check this value before it is being applied to the destination object.